# How to install Confluent 5.3.0 via helm

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed confluent 5.3.0 via helm but I get errors:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
emiconfluent-cp-kafka-0                            1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   3          4m7s
emiconfluent-cp-kafka-1                            1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   3          2m28s
emiconfluent-cp-kafka-2                            1/2     Error              3          2m12s
emiconfluent-cp-kafka-connect-c5946c74f-2hj5b      1/2     Error              3          4m7s
emiconfluent-cp-kafka-rest-59bdf6b45-tzldx         2/2     Running            3          4m7s
emiconfluent-cp-ksql-server-ddfcfb4dd-shkhw        2/2     Running            0          4m7s
emiconfluent-cp-schema-registry-5cf8f864cf-2hcjz   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   3          4m7s
emiconfluent-cp-zookeeper-0                        2/2     Running            1          4m6s
emiconfluent-cp-zookeeper-1                        2/2     Running            0          2m24s
emiconfluent-cp-zookeeper-2                        2/2     Running            0          2m7s
kafka-client                                       1/1     Running            0          2m20s
zookeeper-client                                   1/1     Running            0          2m25s
```

I noticed that many people have this problem.
So I commented the lines from 113 to 117 here:
https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/v5.2.2-1/charts/cp-kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml

Compiled the new chart and installed it with "helm install".
Now it works. But is this the correct solution?